# Angular not working after using services

Tags: angularjs

I was working in Angular without using any service, and it's working fine, until I decided to put my code in a service, now Angular is not working at all. I have multiple files around, so I decided to use plunker to simulate the case. Here's my code: http://goo.gl/Ejkg33

Thank you.

Comment: can you please specify your question? you have not asked an explicit question yet.

Comment: I guess the question is clear, I am saying that before introducing services to my solution, and depending only on controller, my code was working, after I took my code to a service as shown in the code, my code stopped working, and if you open the code you'll see that angular is not working and everything is shown in braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues I found:

1. Your link to angular was broken, that appears to be a plnkr issue though, and not yours. I'll send them a tweet and inform them.
2. githubController and githubService were missing the .js extention.
3. You deleted style.css but didn't remove the reference to it (not effecting the page, but still throwing an error in the console)
4. Returning basically nothing in the service. Updated that (see below)
5. You were forgetting to name the service. See 2nd code block below.

In the service I updated it to return the 2 functions:

```
return {
    getUser: getUser,
    getRepos: getRepos
};
```

Naming the factory:

```
module.factory('github', github);
```

instead of just

```
module.factory(github);
```

Here's an updated plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/T7l0nDP2VK9lYy4utHfI?p=preview

Comment: If you need any of that explained further just let me know and I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Timothy :) When I remove the github service reference from the controller in this line of code:     app.controller('githubController', function ($scope, github, $interval, $log, $anchorScroll, $location) {.. I could see the value of $scope.countdown in the browser, but when I keep the github reference, it shows {{countdown}} and every angular reference in the browser is showing in braces. what's wrong with referencing my service this way? Note am using angular 1.3.15 in my application. Thank you Timothy.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Timothy, my problem was with referencing the return value, it was wrong function name. Thank you Timothy. +1 for the help.